# Data not inserting into the database codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I tried in all possible ways to insert the data into the database but i did not get any kind of output 
This is my controller pages.php

```
<?php

class pages extends CI_Controller {

    function view($page = 'index') {

        $this->load->view('pages/index');

        function insert_data() {
            $this->load->model('contact_model');
            $this->contact_model->insert_entry();
        }

    }

}

?>
```

this is my view view/pages/index.php

```
<form id="submit">

    name <input  type="text" id="name" >    

    email<input type="email" id="email">


    message<textarea id="message"></textarea>              

    <button type="button"  id="submit1">Send</button>
    <a id="ack"></a>         
</form>
```

this is my model models/contact_model

```
<?php

class contact_model extends CI_Model {

    function insert_entry() {
        $data = array(
            'name' => 'name',
            'email' => 'email',
            'message' => 'message');

        $this->db->insert('contactus', $data);
    }
?>
```

this is my custom.js file

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/pages/insert_data",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {"name": $("#name").val(), "email": $("#email").val(), "message": $("#message").val()},
    success: function(data) {
        $("div#ack").html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: `var_dump` your query using `$this->db->last_query()` and run it in to `phpmyadmin`

Comment: You didn't passed posted data to the model.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant

Comment: @user3778654 means you have passed `static` data in database not by getting with form values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove your `insert_data` function from your `view` function, and add it independently from that, and get the posts and pass them to your model like this:

```
class pages extends CI_Controller {

    function view($page = 'index') {
        $this->load->view('pages/index');
    }

    function insert_data(){
        $data = array(
            'name' =>  $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'message' => $this->input->post('message')
        );
        $this->load->model('contact_model');
        $this->contact_model->insert_entry($data);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

}
```

Change your model as below:

```
class contact_model extends CI_Model {

    function insert_entry($data) {
        $this->db->insert('contactus', $data);
    }

}
```

Add on click event to your javascript:

```
$("#submit1").on('click',function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "<?php echo site_url('pages/insert_data');?>",
         type: 'POST',
         data: {"name": $("#name").val(), "email": $("#email").val(), "message": $("#message").val()},
         success: function(data) {
             $("#ack").html(data); // change here too
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: hi, I tried the above solution still its not working

Comment: Are you you have a table called contactus with the columns above with an auto_increment id? I've tried this in my local, there is not any problem, did you get any error also? Please check the console log after you post the form and write here what console log shows.

Comment: this is the error i am getting in the console @Burak POST http://localhost/ci/%3C?php%20echo%20site_url(%27pages/insert_data%27);?%3E 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4
send jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) custom.js:2
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
v.handle jquery.js:4766

Comment: If you have pasted the javascript to your custom.js file then the php can't work, because of that you can't get post to work as logs show, thats why post gets 404 error as a result. Either write the full url within your .js file or copy the javascript part to your view file.